# Android front camera video capture mirroring

Tags: android, video, camera

I am making an application using front camera and recently came up with this issue that outcomes of captured image and video are different(left-right inverted) from what I've seen through the display.

So for the image I could process it right after taking the picture because the size of the image wasn't too big - I used matrix preScale to mirror the image.

However, I have no idea how to do that with video capture. I already know that Android default camera does not mirror the front camera video output and lots of famous applications have compromised with default setting. But at the same time there are some camera related applications such as Instagram, Snow Camera, and B612 that do exactly what I want.

So my questions are,

1. Is it possible to mirror the front camera video output using Android MediaRecorder and Camera class? (That's what I've been using so far)
2. Or do you have to process the video after you take it? And if so, is there any nice and fast way of doing it?

It would be nice if any of you can answer it specifically. Thank you in advance!